# Build Android/iOS librairies from dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am working on a an Android/iOS app using flutter and have been asked to provide Android/iOS native libraries for 3rd-party developers (wrapping web service calls essentially).
Is there a way to generate these libraries from the same dart code?

I've been looking at NDK-type solutions with AOT-compiled dart but I am not sure this approach is do-able.

Comment: Have you seen: [Developing packages & plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) and if you have then update your question with why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Are you looking to create libraries for 3rd-party Flutter developers? Or are you looking to create libraries for native Android and iOS developers?

Comment: @CommonsWare Native Android/iOS

Comment: @MorrisonChang AFAIK Flutter packages are for wrapping Android/iOS code in a common dart interface to be used from Flutter dart code. I'm looking to do the opposite: wrap (probably compiled) dart code in native Java/Kotlin/ObjC/Swift